# mysql query speed is very low

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing

My query is running over more than 500 000 records and causing very slow speed.

here is the query explain:

[image: explain]

and here is my query:

```
SELECT display_name, point_nam, wp__point_scans.Report, DATE_FORMAT(wp__point_scans.Timestamp, '%e %M %Y %H:%i:%s') AS Pretty
FROM wp__point_scans
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp__site_points ON wp__site_points.pID = wp__point_scans.Checkpoint 
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_dh_site_vap ON wp_dh_site_vap.site_id = wp__site_points.site_fk 
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_dh_vaps ON wp_dh_vaps.ID = wp_dh_site_vap.vap 
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_users ON wp_users.ID = wp__point_scans.Name
WHERE pID in (select pID from wp__site_points where site_fk in (select site_id FROM wp_dh_site_vap where ID 
in (SELECT site_id FROM wp_dh_site_access where user_id = 38 and active = 1)));
```

I have tried indexing the columns but not fruitful.

Comment: Please provide table structure with few data and expected output. If possible then few left outer join is converted to inner join.. introduce subquery for retrieving required columns.

Comment: (1) Don't use `IN ( SELECT ... )`, change to `EXISTS( SELECT ...)` or a `INNER JOIN`.  (2) Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table so we can see if you have any useful _composite_ indexes.